# What is the correct way to deploy updates to your Web Application?

Tags: html, versioning

I have a working Web application that consists of an `index.html` file, a number of html pages, a single `js` file, and some `css`.

This is a brand new application and, as expected, there are some minor bugs that made their way to production.

My question is: After I correct the bugs and replace the relevant file, there are good chances that users' browsers will still load buffered versions of the replaced file and hence the correction would not be **seen** by those users.

I found some recommendations about using a version tag (something like `...?version=x.y...`) but it is not clear to me how to use it.

Moreover, if I change (for instance) the name of updated file (e.g. from `ABC_001.html` to `ABC_002.html`) I would also need to change the file that references it, meaning that I would need to change its version as well,... and repeat this till the application's bootstrap point (i.e. `index.html`).

What is the standard method that would deploy the new version of files as soon as they are deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to change the file names, then you will need to change it everywhere where they are referenced. There is no way out of that.

For ensuring that your users always see the updated version of files, using the version number at the end of the links is 1 way. Another way is that you could use the meta tag header in your HTML pages as shown below:

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

Setting this to "no-cache" ensures that the browser always sends a request to the server & doesn't load the cached contents.

You can use the version number technique for your .js & .css files.

Comment: Of course... disabling caching entirely just for ensuring occasional updates will be okay is pretty insane...

Comment: Thank you @user2246620 for your quick response. In fact, there is no single file that could be considered "large", and hence setting no cache would entail a rather negligible cost. As for the versioning of .js and .css, may I kindly ask you to provide a small example on how to use it?

Comment: Do you @deceze have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: @FDavidov For .js & .css files, you could use versioning like this:

`<script src="js/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.2"></script>`

For css, it would be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css?ver=1.2">`

Whether to enable caching or not would also depend on your HTML file contents. So as you said, if it's not that large, then not caching them is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic assumptions:

1. It doesn't really matter if clients get to see a slightly outdated version of your site which still contains bugs; after all, that buggy version presumably has been up there for a few hours/days/weeks already, and a few hours more won't make a big difference.
2. You want to ensure that your visitors get a *consistent* version; i.e. if you have updated two Javascript files, and file A depends on the fixes in file B, then you either want your visitors to have an old version of both files, or the new version of both files, but not an incompatible mix of old and new versions.

To ensure point 2, you'll want to version your files, as you've shown. Simply appending something like `foo.js?v=2` will make the URL different, which makes the browser think it's a different file, and will ensure that it fetches it from the server. *Ideally* your server will actually be able to serve the requested version; i.e. if the browser requests `v=2` it will actually receive version 2 of the file, `v=3` will serve version 3 of the file etc. That may be rather complex to implement though for little benefit.

So what you want is to have an automatic versioning of your assets. This means that you either have a server-side language like PHP which includes all your JS files in your templates and adds a `...?v=...` to them automatically; or that you have a *build system* which does this once before you upload your files to your server. There are many different ways to do this, specific recommendations are a bit out of scope for this answer.

Once you have that, you have one of two cases:

1. A visitor is fetching your up-to-date HTML file from your server, which references versions of Javascript files it doesn't know, which causes it to get those up-to-date files from your server. Exactly what you want.
2. A visitor is visiting a cached version of your HTML file, which references versions of your Javascript files it already has in cache, so it's running entirely of an old cached version of your site. There again, see primary assumption #1, that this isn't really a problem.

There's an unfortunate third case though:

3. A visitor is visiting a cached version of your HTML file, which references outdated versions of your Javascript files, which the browser *does not* happen to have in cache any longer. If your server is not able to actually serve those outdated files, the browser will then fetch the latest up-to-date Javascript files, and you may get into internal compatibility problems because something doesn't match up.

Again, this can be fixed if your server has an actual notion of versioning, but that can be rather complex to implement, and may not be worth it for this somewhat unlikely case.

The most practical way to avoid this case is to choose sensible caching policies for your HTML files, so caches won't be stale for too long and the time window where such a mismatch is possible is reduced to the smallest possible time.

There's basically no need to version the HTML files themselves. The most important thing is that the HTML + the Javascript/CSS assets it references are **consistent**, either all on the same old version or all on the latest version. The version of the HTML itself doesn't matter as much and just influences how up-to-date your site appears, which is something you must control with reasonable caching policies anyway.

Bottomline: automatic versioning of your assets + reasonably short expiration times for the referencing HTML files does the trick in practice for 99% of situations. Squashing the remaining 1% without giving up on caching altogether can be very work intensive.